Group variables into toplevel variables within tbl_summary()
I would like to manually set groups for variables inside the call to tbl_summary. A group of variables should be reported both individually and as a group.
If i had a logical variable apple and a logical variable banana, i would like to report the frequencies of apple and banana, but also for fruits.
Please see below an example with data adapted from dplyr::starwars.
For ease of posting, I included plain markdown tables in this example(not the actual tbl_summary rendered tables), but I believe these explain my issue quite well.
Example data
library(dplyr)
data <-
    starwars |> 
    slice_head(n=20) |> 
    select(gender, sex, eye_color, skin_color, species) |> 
    mutate(male_sex = sex == "male",
           masculine_gender = gender == "masculine",
           human_species = species == "Human",
           blue_eyes = eye_color == "blue",
           light_skin = skin_color == "light",
           .keep = "unused") |> 
    {\(x) filter(x, complete.cases(x))}()  

head(data)
# A tibble: 6 × 5
  male_sex masculine_gender human_species blue_eyes light_skin
  <lgl>    <lgl>            <lgl>         <lgl>     <lgl>     
1 TRUE     TRUE             TRUE          TRUE      FALSE     
2 FALSE    TRUE             FALSE         FALSE     FALSE     
3 FALSE    TRUE             FALSE         FALSE     FALSE     
4 TRUE     TRUE             TRUE          FALSE     FALSE     
5 FALSE    FALSE            TRUE          FALSE     TRUE      
6 TRUE     TRUE             TRUE          TRUE      TRUE      

Vanilla tbl_summary() output with raw data
tbl_summary(data)




Characteristic
N = 191




male_sex
13 (68%)


masculine_gender
17 (89%)


human_species
12 (63%)


blue_eyes
6 (32%)


light_skin
4 (21%)



This is how the final table should look like (note the hierarchical indenting/offsetting):



Characteristic
N = 191




anything_at_all
19 (100%)


  male_or_masculine
17 (89%)


    male_sex
13 (68%)


    masculine_gender
17 (89%)


  human_species
12 (63%)


  blue_or_light
8 (42%)


    blue_eyes
6 (32%)


    light_skin
4 (21%)



I could create the table above with some upstream data manipulation and manual editing of a regular markdown table. However, I would like to know if there is some sort of solution for such grouping strategy implemented in gtsummary.
If i should stick with pre-processing the data, ok, then how do I create the hierarchical indentation?
Code that reproduces the desired table(without the indentation):
data |> 
    mutate(male_or_masculine = if_any(c(male_sex, masculine_gender)),
           .before = male_sex) |> 
    mutate(blue_or_light = if_any(c(blue_eyes, light_skin)),
           .before = blue_eyes) |> 
    mutate(anything_at_all = if_any(male_sex:light_skin),
           .before = everything()) |> 
    tbl_summary()


I think the function bstfun::add_variable_grouping() will do what you need.
https://mskcc-epi-bio.github.io/bstfun/reference/add_variable_grouping.html
set.seed(11234)
add_variable_grouping_ex1 <-
  data.frame(
    race_asian = sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), 20, replace = TRUE),
    race_black = sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), 20, replace = TRUE),
    race_white = sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), 20, replace = TRUE),
    age = rnorm(20, mean = 50, sd = 10)
  ) %>%
  gtsummary::tbl_summary(
    label = list(race_asian = "Asian",
                 race_black = "Black",
                 race_white = "White",
                 age = "Age")
  ) %>%
  add_variable_grouping(
    "Race (check all that apply)" = c("race_asian", "race_black", "race_white")
  )


With the example from the question:
data |> 
    tbl_summary() |> 
    bstfun::add_variable_grouping("male_or_masculine" = c("male_sex",
                                                          "masculine_gender"),
                                  "blue_or_light" = c("blue_eyes", 
                                                      "light_skin"))




That is awesome, @Daniel!
I wonder if this allows nesting the groups?
as in food(fruits(apple, banana), meat(steak, poultry)))?

I edited to include the example from the question. Thank you so much. As for nested groups, i do not believe it is possible, but this is awesome anyway

Proper hierarchical summaries (adverse events within system organ class, drug names within drug classes, etc) are something that I'm thinking about now and will come on the next release or maybe the following
